# Symfony 4 add 4 input type file in EntityType

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I have Entity `Boisson` with rolation with entity `Image` oneToMany 
I have to add 4 image for instance of `Boisson`

Entity `Boisson`

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Image", mappedBy="boisson")
 */
private $images;

/**
 * @return Collection|Image[]
 */
public function getImages(): Collection
{
    return $this->images;
}

public function addImage(Image $image): self
{
    if (!$this->images->contains($image)) {
        $this->images[] = $image;
        $image->setBoisson($this);
    }

    return $this;
}

public function removeImage(Image $image): self
{
    if ($this->images->contains($image)) {
        $this->images->removeElement($image);
        // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
        if ($image->getBoisson() === $this) {
            $image->setBoisson(null);
        }
    }

    return $this;
}
```

End for my `BoissonType`

```
$builder
    ->add('user',EntityType::class, [
        'class' => User::class,
        'query_builder' => function (UserRepository $er) {
            return $er->createQueryBuilder('u');
        },
        'choice_label' => 'username'])
    ->add('nom')
    ->add('prix')
;
```

How can I get 4 input type file to add my image to my boisson

Comment: You can use symfony collection type for it.

Comment: Have you same link explain this please

Comment: change version as per your poject and for Documentation [Click Here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When embedding forms, if you have One to Many relations, the 'many' means you have to use CollectionType in the 'one' Boisson Form as here bellow.

```
$builder->add('images', CollectionType::class, [
    'entry_type' => ImageType::class,

]);
```

Check the docs [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html): for more information on the configuration of this kind of field.